# How do I make a working AND Statement in Discord JS?

Tags: if-statement, discord, discord.js

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const questionString = args.slice(1).join(" ");

if (questionString.includes(("THIS" && "THAT"))) message.channel.send(`Sure thing, <@${message.author.id}>`);
```

So I am trying to make my Bot check if both of these are included in a message. The problem is thought that the bot doesn't react to just "THIS" being in the message, but it reacts when just "THAT" is included in the message which I don't want. I only want the Bot to respond when both "THIS" and "THAT" are included. I couldn't find anything about AND statements in Discord JS and the ones I found for normal JavaScript tutorials always showed it like that. Is it different for Discord JS? And if so what do I have to do to make it work.
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how the [logical AND operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND). If you want to check for both words, you'll have to do it separately. `if (questionString.includes("THIS") && questionString.includes("THAT"))`. If you want to be fancy you could do something like: `if (['THIS', 'THAT'].every(questionString.includes))`

Comment: Ohhh ok thank you so much, even makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

you can not use the AND statement like that. The correct usage will be:

```
if (questionString.includes("THIS") && questionString.includes("THAT"))
```

So your code will end in something like:

```
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const questionString = args.slice(1).join(" ");

if (questionString.includes(("THIS" && "THAT"))) message.channel.send(`Sure thing, <@${message.author.id}>`);
```

You can also use the Array.every funtion, if you use this, you will get something like:

```
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const questionString = args.slice(1).join(" ");
const searchParams = ["THIS", "THAT"];

if (searchParams.every(questionString.includes)) message.channel.send(`Sure thing, <@${message.author.id}>`);
```